# shiny slider with button for increment and decrement

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

Is there a possibility for sliders in shiny to have buttons for increment and decrement, instead of dragging the slider?

Comment: If you use `observeEvent` for your `input$button` that includes an `updateSliderInput` to increase the selected value by doing something like `selected = input$slider+1` I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe my package `shinyChakraSlider` is suitable. The `chakraSliderInput` combines a slider and a number input:

[image]

Here is the code generating the app you see on this GIF:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyChakraSlider)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  chakraSliderInput("slider", value = 5, min = 0, max = 10, step = 0.5,
                    width = "50%", size = "lg",
                    numberInputOptions = numberInputOptions(
                      width = "25%",
                      fontSize = "15px", 
                      fontColor = "navyblue",
                      borderColor = "yellow",
                      borderWidth = "medium",
                      focusBorderColor = "navyblue",
                      stepperColor = c("palegreen", "palevioletred")
                    ),
                    trackColor = c("red", "blue"),
                    thumbOptions = thumbOptions(
                      width = "40px",
                      height = "30px",
                      color = "pink",
                      borderColor = "magenta",
                      borderWidth = "2px",
                      icon = "arrows",
                      iconSize = "2em"
                    )
  ),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["value"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["slider"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To install this package:

```
devtools::install_github("stla/shinyChakraInput")
```